# capture bash script with espeak commands in audio file

Tags: bash, espeak

I have a script that reads out text using espeak. the scripts reads out a line of text and then sleeps for a predefined time and the reads again and so on.

I would like to capture the output in an audiofile. However when using:

./script_name.sh -- stdout > audio

no audio goes into the file.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                     
sleep   19                                      
        espeak  '   14  Pylon                       '
sleep   20                                      
        espeak  '   15  Gateway                     '
sleep   8                                       
        espeak  '   16  Assimilator                     '
sleep   38                                      
        espeak  '   20  Nexus
```

What can I do to capture the espeak sound into a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it like this.

```
sleep   19                                      
        espeak --stdout '   14  Pylon                       '
sleep   20                                      
        espeak --stdout '   15  Gateway                     '
sleep   8                                       
        espeak --stdout '   16  Assimilator                     '
sleep   38                                      
        espeak --stdout '   20  Nexus
```

If you want stdout printing to be optional you can do:

```
if [[ -n "$1" ]] && [[ "$1" == "--stdout" ]]; then
sleep   19                                      
        espeak --stdout '   14  Pylon                       '
sleep   20                                      
        espeak --stdout '   15  Gateway                     '
sleep   8                                       
        espeak --stdout '   16  Assimilator                     '
sleep   38                                      
        espeak --stdout '   20  Nexus  '
else 
sleep   19                                      
        espeak '   14  Pylon                       '
sleep   20                                      
        espeak  '   15  Gateway                     '
sleep   8                                       
        espeak  '   16  Assimilator                     '
sleep   38                                      
        espeak  '   20  Nexus  '
fi
```

Then if you pass script.sh --stdout it will work.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Furkan. It works just as you explained. Nice feature with the if-statement. I will try it out.